# MySQL Select by (Varchar) Time

Tags: php, mysql, time

I'm managing the date and time in my database. In the *backend/PhpMyAdmin*, its *column type* is ***Varchar***.

It is old and and not correctly made system, but it's really huge and changing the *column type* to ***date*** or ***integer*** would cost a lot of time.

My question is: How to select ordering by `time_column` in 00:00 format (g:i)?

It looks like that (works fine but problem is with the time lower than *10 h 9:00, 8:00*)

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM l01vs_database ORDER BY time ASC");
```

I tried

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM l01vs_database ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(time,'%g:%i') ASC");
```

But I am not ever sure if it is correct.

Comment: Expand on what you mean by "problem is with times lower then 10 h 9:00, 8:00"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using the wrong syntax variables. You are using '%g:%i', but shouldn't this be '%H:%i'?

```
"SELECT * FROM l01vs_database ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(time,'%H:%i') ASC"
```

If you have the twelve hour format, you can use '%h'. Take a look at this page for more information: http://www.w3cyberlearnings.com/Mysql_STR_TO_DATE

Comment: Great answer, now I understand what OP meant :)

Comment: Thx a lot simple exmplanation and advice to the future

Answer (score 0):

Depending on wether the date was entered as 24h format or not, you might want to change the `STR_TO_DATE(time,'%g:%i')` to `STR_TO_DATE(time,'%H:%i')`. You'll have the leading zeros and that way you won't have problems with the 9:00 and 8:00. If it was entered as 12h format, then use the lower "h"